# Magento change product page layout (catalog.xml is NOT working)

Tags: magento-1.7

As I know, we can only do that by hand, and must must edit the `“catalog.xml” file here: app > design > frontend > default > myskin > layout > catalog.xml.` Do a search for “Product view” and change the code:

```
<reference name="root">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

and i already set 2columns-right.phtml there,  but it still is using 2columns-left.phtml !

Who know how I can figure out this problem ?  thanks.

Comment: Have you clear the cache folder?.

Comment: yes, i just deleted all files under /var/cache, also i disabled all options under cache management of admin....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need to change catalog.xml here,

```
Open up app > design > frontend > default > deault > layout > catalog.xml
```

Check there which template is assigned?. if it is not "2columns-right.phtml" change that.

Comment: there is no xml under the path as you mentioned,  but when i change the path /app/design/frontend/default to /app/design/frontend/default2, the site still is working, the means the default skin is /app/design/frontend/base/default, but in /base/defult/layout/catalog.xml, product view page is using 2columns-right.phtml, but after my checking, the front page still is using 2columns-left.phtml ! so strange ! what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

i got ~

i forgot to set NO for Apply To Products ~

[image]